# How to do AppEngine Go 1.16 local development?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-golang

AppEngine supports Go 1.16 for a year now. But dev_appengine.py still doesn't:

```
RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'go116'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'go111', 'go112', 'go113', 'go114', 'go115', 'java', 'java7', 'java8', 'php55', 'php72', 'php81', 'python', 'python-compat', 'python27', 'python310', 'python37', 'python38', 'python39'.
```

The official documentation is unhelpful.

How can I do local Go 1.16 development of my AppEngine app?

Comment: Why do you need an emulator? Do you use App Engine specific APIs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - if you need to test route handlers in ```app.yaml``` file, or test that multi-service Apps (make sure ```dispatch.yaml```) is correctly working, you'll need to run your App with ```dev_appserver.py```. If you also wish to view the contents of your local datastore, you'll need that tool unless you use 3rd party GUIs built for the datastore emulator

Comment: Understood. And I don't have any solution. You can try to build a container and set your to custom your emulator env.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/OspOyUz7CBQ - it seems like the Go version of AppEngine is no longer supported at Google...

Comment: Don't see anything in that google group link that says so.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant `dev_appserver.py` and not `dev_appengine.py`. If so, then

1. It looks like you're using GAE Standard env in which case, `gcloud CLI version 409.0.0` (which seems to be the latest, at least for Mac) doesn't support `go 1.1.6.` The go runtimes supported in it are

```
 go, go111, go112, go113, go114, go115
```

```
You can find the list of supported runtimes in the file 

{{path to gcloud sdk_installation}}/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/runtime_factories.py
```

2. If you switch to GAE Flex, I believe you'll be able to use go 1.1.6 since you'll then be using a `custom` runtime
3. You can also just run your App as you would a standard go App e.g using command `go run <go_package>`